# from tensorflow.keras.utilis import to_categorical

Tags: tensorflow, keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yirMz.png)

anyone here knows how to fix this? already downloaded the keras and tensorflow yet still cant find the module for this one

Im currently using python 3.9 and pycharm, hopefully can fix this problem and still using pycharm in the end

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake(utils) while importing the [to_categorical](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical) api from tensorflow.

**Please use code as below:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```